# TextView onClcikclistener seems not being working

Tags: java, android

The onClickListener on this TextView seems not be working when I click the text in the app it doesn't show the TimePickerDialog or anything .Should I use a TouchListener ? Whats the problem? Please help thanks in advance --Emanuel.

Here is the code:

```
hora_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        hora_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick (View v){
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,hourSetListener,hora,minutos,true);
                    mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    mTimePicker.show();
                 }
             });

         hourSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
             @Override
             public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hora, int minutos) {
                 hora_text.setText(hora+":"+minutos);
             }
         };
    }
});

date_text.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_button.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            DatePickerDialog date_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),                            
                                           android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                                           dateSetListener,
                                            year, month, day);
                            date_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            date_dialog.show();
                        };
                    }
            );

            dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                    month=month + 1;
                    String dt = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    try {
                        sdf.parse(dt);
                        date_text.setText(dt);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: All you're doing inside the click listeners for your TextViews is assigning listeners to your buttons. Looking at the code you've posted, you might see your TimePickers appear if you press the text view `hora_text`, and then afterwards press `hora_button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @PPartisan mentioned in the comments, you're not really setting the TextView clickable with functionality since you're setting the functionality within a button instead. So in your case, it should be:

```
hora_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,hourSetListener,hora,minutos,true);
        mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mTimePicker.show();
    }
);
```